# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat6, sslhandshakeexception

I've problem with authorized ssl connection in Tomcat. I've developed class that connects to external server with certificate. It works fine when I run it in command line. But when I call it from JSP page that hosts in Tomcat throws exception like this:

> error:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174) com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136) com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1694) com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:939) com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1120) com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1147) com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1131) sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434) sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166) sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1049) sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234) myPakage.myClass.method(myClass.java:90) org.apache.jsp.jsp.test.tst_jsp._jspService(tst_jsp.java:66) org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:554) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859) org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) 
>   Blockquote

I have imported already external server's public certificate to cacerts in java home.
Version of Java: 6.0_21
Version of Tomcat: 6.0.32

I'm really tired with this problem. Please, help to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you set up the keystore? And are you reading it correctly?

Comment: Did you setup the certificate and https connection in Tomcat?

Comment: Yes? I give to class absolute path to keystore and kaystore password. After that myClass connects to the server with that parameters

Comment: It reads correctly keystore parameters, when I run my class in command line I give same parameters like with JSP calling.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the same problem now, upgrade to java 1.6.0_32. Had the same problem and it has been solved after upgrade.